# Step down 5V Power supply for IoT

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, ac-dc, step-down

I am trying to create common DC power supply to support ESP32 Development board, Servo Moter (MG995) & Fan Motor (0.2A), all required 5V DC. I am considering Hi-Link 5V 4A SMPS Mini PCB Mounted HLK-20M05 AC-DC 220V to 5V Step Down Power Supply. Planning to do straight connection as follows.

AC (220V) ---> HLK-20M05 ---> DC 5V (4A)

Was wondering if I need to add any additional component to make all (ESP32, Servo & Fan Motor) together.

Appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Comment: It looks OK. Since it is a development board consider how you will isolate the 220V input to prevent a shock hazard. Have you considered over current protection in case something gets miss wired while working on a prototype? Considering all the extra hardware the supplier recommends Adafruit offers an all in one. https://www.adafruit.com/product/1466  Have fun with your project.

Comment: use a cap or two on the output, 470u and a 10u work well.